# The problem with changing the properties of the autocad block on python

Tags: python, autocad

I have a function that inserts a “Block_test” block into an autocad drawing. Then I search for this block in the space of the autocad model, find its properties of this block, change one of the properties to the value I need. Up to this point, the code worked fine. But as soon as I insert the block again, changing the Y coordinate, this block is no longer searched for as dynamic. Line of code “print(i.efficientename)” does not output the name of this block. Accordingly, it is impossible to edit this block. How can I solve this problem? Please help me!!!

```
from pyautocad import Autocad, APoint
acad = Autocad(create_if_not_exists=True)

boxes_list = [“Box1′, ‘Box2’] # List block names
cor_x = 0
cor_y = 0
n = 5

def create_box_to_autocad(name_box, x, y): 
  block_table_box = acad.model.InsertBlock(APoint(x, y), ‘Block_test’, 1, 1, 1, 0) # Insert block_test
  for i in acadModel:                                          # looking for objects in the model space
    if i.IsDynamicBlock:                                            # if the block is dynamic
      print(i.EffectiveName)                                  
      if i.EffectiveName == “Block_test”:                #  if the block name matches the specified one
        for p in i.GetDynamicBlockProperties():        #  looking through the properties of the block
          if p.PropertyName == ‘Length’:                  #  if there is such a property
          p.Value *= n                                   # changing the value of the property
          block_table_box.ConvertToStaticBlock(“static_Block_test-” + name_box)

for box in boxes_list:                                #  we cycle through the list of names
  create_box_to_autocad(box, cor_x, cor_y)         #   passing the name and coordinates to the function
  cor_y -= 350                                        # changing the Y coordinate
  n += 1
```

I tried changing the block name, it doesn't work. I tried to do a search by the name of the object and by the name of the block, it does not work. I converted the block after inserting it into a static one, it doesn't work either. I tried to find the block by attributes. Attributes could not be read. I will be glad of any help

As a result, I want to get the following: insert a block in the autocad - change its property. Put the block again and change the property of this block already, and so on.

Comment: You do not need to search the block reference you inserted, it is stored in your `block_table_box` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this (not tested)

```
def create_box_to_autocad(name_box, x, y): 
  block_table_box = acad.model.InsertBlock(APoint(x, y), ‘Block_test’, 1, 1, 1, 0) # Insert block_test
  for p in block_table_box.GetDynamicBlockProperties():        #  looking through the properties of the block
    if p.PropertyName == ‘Length’:                  #  if there is such a property
      p.Value *= n                                   # changing the value of the property
  block_table_box.ConvertToStaticBlock(“static_Block_test-” + name_box)
```

Comment: Return an error:

File "C:\Users\Dimai\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\lazybind.py", line 182, in caller
    return self._comobj._invoke(descr.memid, descr.invkind, 0, *args)
  File "C:\Users\Dimai\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\comtypes\automation.py", line 747, in _invoke
    return var._get_value(dynamic=True)
  File "C:\Users\Dimai\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\comtypes\automation.py", line 467, in _get_value
    typ = _vartype_to_ctype[self.vt & ~VT_ARRAY]
KeyError: 9